# ASP.NET Core - IStartupFilter equivalent for ConfigureServices?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need something to extend my middleware pipeline with new `ConfigureServices` methods. I'm already using the `IStartupFilter` class which works great for the `Configure` method, but I'm looking to achieve the same for the `ConfigureServices` method.

I read online about the `IStartupConfigureServicesFilter` class, but it's deprecated and no longer in use ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupconfigureservicesfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0)).

Is there anything else I can use to achieve this?

Comment: "achieve this" - what exactly do you mean with "this"? `ConfigureServices` registers services and does nothing with your pipeline, so you can't do "the same" here. It's difficult to guess because a) in most applications there's no need to use IStartupFilter and b) the service container is something that you configure once,... so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Look at all the framework supplied middleware. Most of them have a `services.Add[Something]` extension method, and an `app.Use[Something]` extension method. Why are you trying to do anything different?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [StartupModules NuGet](https://github.com/henkmollema/StartupModules) , it gives you the ability to separate startup configuration.

***Be careful with middlewares, because those modules will not be ordered at runtime.***